# NA errors when converting datetime column in R

Tags: r, datetime

I'm trying to convert a column to a date-time format in R. I've tried the following conversion but it fills my output as `NA`:

```
migtimes$mig_start<- format(migtimes$mig_start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
migtimes$mig_start<-strptime(x = as.character(migtimes$mig_start), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
migtimes$mig_start <- as.POSIXct(strptime(migtimes$mig_start , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz ="MST") 
migtimes$mig_start<- strptime(x = as.character(migtimes$mig_start),
         format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ymd_hms( as.character(migtimes$mig_start),tz ="MST" )
```

For the `ymd_hms`conversion I also get an NA error :

```
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Here's what my dataframe looks like. When I read in my csv file it says the `mig_start` (which is my date field) is a factor. I want to convert this field to a `2018-12-13 22:00:00` format. I'm at a loss of what else I can try. Any suggestions?

```
X    mig_start    
1 3/20/2019 11:00 
2 4/3/2019 15:00
3 3/17/2019 22:00 
4 3/6/2019 12:00 
5 3/6/2019 12:00 
6 5/3/2019 5:01
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is wrong. You have month/day/year hour:minute.

Using `lubridate`, you can use `mdy_hm()`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

migtimes<- migtimes %>% 
  mutate(dt = mdy_hm(mig_start))
```

Result:

```
  X       mig_start                  dt
1 1 3/20/2019 11:00 2019-03-20 11:00:00
2 2  4/3/2019 15:00 2019-04-03 15:00:00
3 3 3/17/2019 22:00 2019-03-17 22:00:00
4 4  3/6/2019 12:00 2019-03-06 12:00:00
5 5  3/6/2019 12:00 2019-03-06 12:00:00
6 6   5/3/2019 5:01 2019-05-03 05:01:00
```

Data:

```
migtimes <- structure(list(X = 1:6, 
                         mig_start = c("3/20/2019 11:00", "4/3/2019 15:00", "3/17/2019 22:00", 
                                       "3/6/2019 12:00", "3/6/2019 12:00", "5/3/2019 5:01")), 
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a matter of the format string you provided. You want it to match the strings you are converting, not the format you want the dates to print with. Try this:

```
migtimes <- data.frame(
    X = 1:6,
    mig_start = c("3/20/2019 11:00", "4/3/2019 15:00", "3/17/2019 22:00", 
        "3/6/2019 12:00", "3/6/2019 12:00", "5/3/2019 5:01")
)
migtimes$mig_start <- as.POSIXct(migtimes$mig_start, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", 
    tz = fill.this.in.with.whatever.is.appropriate.for.you)
```

You could also try `as.POSIXlt` instead of `as.POSIXct`, whichever you're more comfortable dealing with.